# WPF Binding rows of datagrid together

Tags: wpf

I have a class as follows

```
class DataGridItem
{
    public bool IsSpecial;
    public string Symbol;
    public double Weight;
}
```

An editable datagrid is bound to a collection of objects of this class. What I need to do is to bind several rows of the datagrid together. That is, whenever `IsSpecial` is `true`, the `Weight` field of all rows must be the same. If I edit one row, it has to automatically modify all other rows where `IsSpecial` is `true`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the CellEditEnding/RowEditEnding and the InitializingNewItem events and change all the items in there. Remember to call the PropertyChanged handlers for every property changed so the grid does update!